# wget --no-check-certificate mirror

Tags: linux, wget, cpanel

I am trying to use wget to mirror a full website I have created. I am wondering why this bit in the terminal won't work:

```
    wget --mirror-no-check-certificate [my site goes here]
```

I am also trying to get a site that doesn't contain a robotics.txt so if anyone knows a workaround that would be great.

***thanks in advance guys.***

Comment: What specific error message are you receiving? As a quick starting point, make sure you have a space between the mirror command and the no check: "wget --mirror --no-check-certificate [my site goes here]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because there is no option called `--mirror-no-check-certificate`.

You may have intended to use the two separate options `--mirror` and `--no-check-certificate`:

```
wget --mirror --no-check-certificate [your site goes here]
```

Comment: is it possible to get something to scan the files without the site's robotics.txt ?

Comment: Yes, you can ask a search engine [how to get wget to ignore robots.txt](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20get%20wget%20to%20ignore%20robots.txt)